# Declare optional last element in array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, optional-parameters

I want to declare a Typescript array type in which the last element is optional. Is there any **elegant** way to achieve this?

```
const test = (a: [string, string, any | undefined]) => console.log(a)
test(['foo', 'bar'])
```

In the `test(...)` function call, ts verbose this error

```
Argument of type '[string, string]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, string, any]'.
  Property '2' is missing in type '[string, string]' but required in type '[string, string, any]'.(2345)
```

Comment: Note these are called tuple types which is useful to know if you want to find documentation on them.

Answer (score 7):

```
const test = (a: [string, string, any?]) => console.log(a)
test(['foo', 'bar'])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A better pattern would be to use generics so you don't have to declare types for each of array elements as follows `const test = (a: Array<string|undefined|null>) => console.log(a)
test(['foo', 'bar', ,"etc"])`. This lets you create an array with string or undefined/null elements.